# Access multiple bits in bitset

Tags: c++

I am writing up a cache simulator, in which 32 bits address is used. I use bitset<32> to store the address. A problem comes across when I try to access multiple bits of address to decode. For example:

```
int index = address[index_MSB, index_LSB].to_ulong();
```

I try to access some bits in address and converting to int. It causes errors. 
Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

example:

address = 0x12345678;

index_MSB = 5;

index_LSB = 2;

I would need 4 bits from address[2] to address[5], here is 1110, and convert to int value: 14.

Comment: Please clarify your question with an example, of the "when `address` is `this`, and `something else` is `that`, I want `index` to be `something`" type... Right now not sure what you are asking... What is the value of `index_MSB` and `index_LSB`?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to access a bit in a number is to do a AND operation between the number and a mask. For example

```
number = 0xFFAA0055; // an example
bit17 = 1 << 17;     // counting bit0 as the least significant bit

bit17set = number & bit17;
```

bit17set will be `true` if bit 17 is `1`, since only then will the logical `AND` produce a non-zero result.

If you are interested in multiple bits, you can simply sum their masks before the AND:

```
bit6 = 1 << 6;

bit6or17 = bit6 + bit17;
bit6or17set = number & bit6or17;
```

When you want the address bits from MSB to LSB, the easiest operation is:

```
temp = number >> LSB; // this shifts LSB numbers to the right
answer = temp & ((1<<(MSB-LSB+1) - 1); // a mask of MSB-LSB bits
```

You could of course combine these two:

```
int index = ((address >> index_LSB) & (1<<(index_MSB - index_LSB+1)-1)).to_ulong();
```

Note: all the above assume "normal" numbers with bits stored "conventionally". If your `address` contains bits in a way that cannot be accessed by the above method, you can do the following instead:

```
int ii, index=0;
for(ii=index_MSB; ii>= index_LSB; ii--) {
    index = (index << 1) + address[ii];
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it- which of the two methods did you use? Mask, or loop? Can you "accept" the answer?